# Error while creating Heroku pipeline from VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx, heroku, vs-code

So, I am trying to create Heroku pipeline from VSCode. I ran the command `./setup.sh`

In my `setup.sh` file I've set `HEROKU_APP_NAME` and verified "Usernames or aliases of the orgs you're using" and also set the `PACKAGE_NAME` as well. For now, I'm not authorising the Github yet.

When the command `./setup.sh` is ran, its creating the apps in my Github (developer, staging, production) but its failing to create Pipeline. Everytime I run it, it stops with error

> ERROR: Did not find 'Sfdx Auth Url' output from command: sfdx force:org:display --verbose -u DevOrg

or

> ERROR: Did not find 'Sfdx Auth Url' output from command: sfdx force:org:display --verbose -u DevHub

If I run these commands `sfdx force:org:display --verbose -u DevHub` separately, I am getting the Sfdx Auth Url output as well.

[image]

I tried to change the line `devSfdxAuthUrl=$(sfdx force:org:display --verbose -u DevOrg | grep "Sfdx Auth Url" | awk '{ print $4 }')` **to** `devSfdxAuthUrl = "actual Sfdx Auth Url return from above command in pic"` but with no luck.

Its also showing that Setting `SFDX_CREATE_PACKAGE_VERSION` false as below

> Setting SFDX_CREATE_PACKAGE_VERSION and restarting ⬢ sagi20190519-dev... done, v8
>   SFDX_CREATE_PACKAGE_VERSION: true
>
> Setting SFDX_CREATE_PACKAGE_VERSION and restarting ⬢ sagi20190519-staging... done, v8
>   SFDX_CREATE_PACKAGE_VERSION: false
>
> Setting SFDX_CREATE_PACKAGE_VERSION and restarting ⬢ sagi20190519-prod... done, v8
>   SFDX_CREATE_PACKAGE_VERSION: false

Please help me understand how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please include the (relevant portions of the) actual script you are running.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for replying. I actually was able to resolve the issue by changing the RegEx. I've changed the condition check from       if [[ "$devSfdxAuthUrl" =~ ^force://.*\.salesforce\.com$ ]];    to     if [[ "$devSfdxAuthUrl" =~ ^force://.*\.salesforce\.com/$ ]];.     When script ran and it fetches scratch org url, instead of checking for ....salesforce.com/,  I was just checing for .....salesforce.com (/ at the end).

Comment: That's valuable information. Would you consider writing an answer to your own question to help other members of the community?

Answer (score 0):

So, when the script ran and fetching the URLs of HubOrg and Scratch Orgs, for HubOrg, the return url is in ....salesforce.com format and for scratch orgs, the url is in ....salesforce.com/ format.

Before modifying, my RegEx was like below for both Devhub and Scratch orgs

Devhub:
if [[ "$devHubSfdxAuthUrl" =~ ^force://.*.salesforce.com$ ]];

Scratch org:
if [[ "$devSfdxAuthUrl" =~ ^force://.*.salesforce.com$ ]];

So, I've modified the scratch org's RegEx to ('/' at the end)

if [[ "$devSfdxAuthUrl" =~ ^force://.*.salesforce.com/$ ]];

We can also try and remove the last char of returned 'Sfdx Auth Url'.